# IllegalStateException while connecting with PHP from Java

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, android-studio

I'm beginner in java and Android Studio, and I'm sitting over the following problem:

I'm trying to send SQL query from Java app to a (working) PHP script, which performs the received SELECT command, and the app reads in the selection's result.

What causes the error? :/ Thank you in advance for your help.

My error log: https://hastebin.com/goqabajuyo.sql
PHP script: https://hastebin.com/otigopufeq.xml

```
 public void query(String query) throws IOException {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/db_query.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String postData = URLEncoder.encode("mysql_query","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");

        bufferedWriter.write(postData);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, just a guess:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got the solution, just have to run the query method as AsyncTask.

```
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```